# How can install the catalyst/flgrx driver, for only a single kernel version (or GRUB menu entry)?

Tags: drivers, grub2, ati, graphics, radeon

A while ago, I attempted to install `flgrx` on a machine with an AMD/ATI Radeon 6480g (SUMO) on an APU, which ended poorly and ended up requiring a reinstall because of the config being thoroughly messed up (including losing the `radeon` open-source driver). This was all on a 64-bit clean install of Trusty.

I would like to try this again, with a newer version of the Catalyst drivers (also on a 64-bit clean install of Trusty). However, seeing as this is my primary machine and has been extensively configured, I would like to avoid the risk of corrupting graphics configuration greatly.

Is there a way that I can install the Catalyst/flgrx drivers, such that I can choose between loading them, and loading the open-source `radeon` driver that I am currently using? I was thinking about tying them to a specific kernel version that I already have installed (and is known to work). This is based on the (possibly incorrect) assumption that whether the drivers are loaded is controlled by the initrd/initramfs and/or the command line that Grub passes to the kernel.

Could someone clarify whether this is doable, and how I would go about doing it? I am OK manually moving Xorg or other configuration files in by hand if absolutely necessary. However, it is key for me that until I know the driver works stably, I have a `radeon` configuration that works, and my current kernel (as well as any new kernel versions/revisions installed by updates) still contains and loads `radeon`.

My kernel is 3.13.0-55-generic, and I have old kernels as far as 3.13.0-24-generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete step-by-step solution, but you look experienced enough. :-)

Fglrx driver is installed using dkms.

You can always remove this diver for a specific kernel by command

```
sudo dkms remove <module_name>/<module_version> -k <kernel_version>
```

module_name is `fglrx` or `fglrx_pci` if I remember it correct.

Also you can edit `/usr/src/<module_name>-<module_version>/dkms.conf` and remove `AUTOINSTALL=yes` from there.

But the problem may be in installation scripts that may blacklist radeon driver. So it needs some research in the deb package and testing.

So it is feasible, but IMHO it is not worth efforts.

You can always install fglrx from a deb package, and if something goes wrong just remove it from console.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at the package contents and see if there is in fact a blacklist. Both of these steps (dkms and checking blacklists) were ones I missed when I was first trying it.

Comment: @hexafraction I updated the answer. Do not forget to remove AUTOINSTALL. You can find what this variable does in dkms.conf easily in the net.

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with Xorg--is `/etc/Xorg.conf` the only thing outside the kernel/module management I'd need to back up? Or, do I need to back up or change other Xorg-related files?

Comment: xorg.conf is not necessary in Ubuntu now. And it is located at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf` and there are some other files in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. But it may be that there is no that file at all.

Comment: It is interesting for me too. But I do not have any hardware now with AMD cards. I would get it working, maybe even build a custom deb.